# Is it possible to pass or get variables through AS3 and Batch files?

Tags: actionscript-3, batch-file

How to pass or get variables through AS3 and Batch files?

Actually My main app is in Flash CS5. I want to search root folder (Which is not possible only with AS3 alone) for number of directories and pass them to a batch file. What is the best solution? Thanks for reading the question.

Comment: You can not do this on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You need a server to do that: have a PHP script that loops through the folder and returns the list as JSON or XML. Then call this script from Flash.